# update containment bounds while dragging a jQuery UI draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a way to update the jQuery UI draggable components bounds **while dragging** it. My use case is a box that has `containment` set to `"parent"`, but dynamically resizes downwards when it hits the bottom edge. Currently, I can drag and when it hits the bottom edge, it will resize, but I have to drop the element to move it down again and force a resize.  I've found the [offending lines](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/draggable.js#L534-L560) in the jQuery UI project that cause this behaviour. I've also tried the solutions detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629864/jquery-ui-draggable-exceed-containment-on-one-side) answer, but they don't seem to work for the use case that has a bottom that can expand indefinitely. For all intents and purposes, my demo is the exact same as detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629864/jquery-ui-draggable-exceed-containment-on-one-side/17661664#17661664) answer. Is there a way to let jQuery UI know that I want to keep moving an element down?